# Can Generics be used to define optional parameters in methods in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, optional-parameters

I have an interface, `IFoo`, that implements one method, `Bar`. `IFoo` accepts a generic argument `T`. This generic argument defines the type of the parameter accepted by `Bar`.

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    public void Bar(T value);
}
```

Pretty basic. But, sometimes, it is not necessary for `Bar` to accept any arguments. To implement this, I have created a second interface, also called `IFoo`, that does not accept any generic arguments.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    public void Bar();
}
```

This works, but it adds overhead anytime I might want to update `IFoo`, given that there are technically two different `IFoo`s. If I want to add a second method to the interface(s) I now have to do it twice. This also impacts any classes that implement `IFoo` if I have a class `Baz` that implements `IFoo` and I want it to implement both versions of `IFoo`, I have to define one version of `Baz` that passes a generic to `IFoo` and one that does not. For instance:

```
public class Baz<T> : IFoo<T>
{
    private IFoo<T> _command;

    public void Bar(T value) {
        _command.Bar(value);
    }
}
```

```
public class Baz : IFoo
{
    private IFoo _command;

    public void Bar() {
        _command.Bar();
    }
}
```

Both classes, `Baz` are fairly similar. They both pass a function call to another `IFoo` object. But since one takes an argument, and the other does not, they have to be two different classes, despite the fact that their functionality is nearly identical. Whatever changes I make to one I am guaranteed to make to the other. It would be ideal to have one class `Baz` that can be instantiated with or without a generic depending on what type of argument it is meant to take and whether or not it should even take an argument at all.

```
// This code works with the two versions of Baz defined above.
// The goal would be to get this code to work with only one Baz class.

var intBaz = new Baz<int>();
var stringBaz = new Baz<string>();
var emptyBaz = new Baz();

intBaz.Bar(100);
stringBaz.Bar("It would be really nice if this is possible, thank you");
emptyBaz.Bar();
```

Is there anyway, within C#, to define an interface `IFoo` that determines not only what type of argument its method `Bar` accepts, but also whether or not `Bar` accepts any argument at all? Thanks!

So far I have been able to work around this problem by implementing two, nearly identical, interfaces `IFoo` and `IFoo<T>`. This "works" to an extent but makes classes that implements `IFoo` and `IFoo<T>` difficult to maintain, as any class that implements one requires a second class that implements the other. Changes to one class must be reflected in changes to the other. At best, this adds time to development. At worst, this introduces vulnerabilities for the code to become out of sync.

Comment: Classes can implement multiple interfaces, so any class can implement either one or both of those interfaces. You could also declare both methods in the generic interface of have the generic interface extend the non-generic one.

Comment: That's true. That doesn't quite meet the needs of my project, though. Each `Baz` class should only have one signature for its Bar method. The `Bar` method on `bazInt`, for example, should not be callable without an integer argument. Conversely, the `Bar` method on `emptyBaz` should only be callable with any arguments. My goal is to improve the overall maintainability while leaving the functionality unchanged. But, I appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: Just tweak your implementation with inheritance. Check if this works for you.    

public interface IFoo
    {
        void Bar();
    }

    public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo
    {
        void Bar(T value);
    }

    public class Baz : IFoo
    {
        IFoo _command;
        public void Bar()
        {
            _command.Bar();
        }
    }

    public class Baz<T> : Baz, IFoo<T>
    {
        private IFoo<T> _command;
        public void Bar(T value)
        {
            _command.Bar(value);
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

I would define a [`Unit` type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) - a type that only has one valid value.

```
struct Unit {}
```

And use that on the generic interface whenever you want to say "I don't want arguments". This way, you can get rid of the non-generic interface.

Of course, you still have to pass `new()`, but since that is the only value for this type, you are not actually giving any information, or doing any thinking.

```
var emptyBaz = new Baz<Unit>();
emptyBaz.Bar(new());
```

An alternative formulation is a class that cannot be instantiated:

```
var emptyBaz = new Baz<Unit>();
emptyBaz.Bar(null);

sealed class Unit {
    private Unit() {}
}
```

The only value for this type is `null`, so this might require you to do more null checking in your implementations.

Similar problems exist in the standard library, like `(Value)Task<T>` and `(Value)Task` etc. I don't think an "elegant" solution exists yet. If it did, the standard library would have used it.

Comment: I'd say `Action` and `Func<T>` is different , but very related problem of return type (neither `void` for return type nor "missing" for parameter can be expressed in C#).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ah, I see what you mean, and I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default implementation to provide the second method, which will give the  implementing class an option to have a different implementation for both if needed:

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    public void Bar(T value);
    
    public void Bar() {Bar(default(T)!);}
}
```

Or actually provide default parameter to the interface:

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    public void Bar(T value = default(T)!);
}
```

There is really no wayto implement a single class that is and isn't generic at the same time - you have to have two classes for that and two interfaces. You still can use default implementation  in the generic interface to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Interesting idea! It seems though that every class that implements `IFoo` would have access to a version of the `Bar` method that accepts no arguments, which is not the desired result. For instance: 


`var intBaz = new Baz<int>();`

`intBaz.Bar(100); // This is acceptable`

`intBaz.Bar(); // This should not compile`


Am I mistaken?

Comment: I suspect I read too much in title of the post - after re-reading the question you are asking about having two totally incompatible methods (one with parameter and another without) somehow to be represented by one *something*... I'm pretty sure such thing does not exist in C#.

Comment: `intBaz.Bar();` indeed will not compile (as you likely tried)... But that is not what you should be trying to compile according to the question :)

Comment: I see. Thank you. But if `public void Bar();` is defined in the `IFoo<T>` interface, why would this not compile?

Comment: Default implementations are a bit weird. The interface implements the method, but the class does not. To the caller, they appear to behave in a similar way to explicit interface implementations. So `intBaz.Bar()` won't compile, but `((IFoo<T>)intBaz).Bar()` does.